# Flash Timer Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

So I'm trying to create a timer in flash, just a basic timer. I have looked at some tutorials on Google and found a couple of good ones. Problem that I'm running into is when I try to create the timer on a different screen. I have made the dynamic text box `myText`. When I try to access `myText` it gives me `Game Screen, Layer 'AS3', Frame 156, Line 11, Column 2    1120: Access of undefined property myText.`

This is what my code looks like when calling the timer:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var count :Number=60;
var myTimer :Timer=new Timer(1000, count);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.start();

function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    myText.text=String((count)-myTimer.currentCount);
}
```

I have followed the tutorial to a T and keep getting the issue. `Am I creating the text box wrong? Do I need to add the text box to the screen I want it on? Do I need to create a movie clip with the text box in it?` I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to add the text box to the screen I want it on?

Yes. As error states, your text field can't be reached at keyframe, where you placed code with timer. Also, if you have text field already on the desired keyframe, I think you forgot to give it a name, check this moment also.

[image: Information]

Comment: Ok, I seem to have gotten it. I didn't initiate it in my code at the top. I added `public var myText :TextField` at the top of my code and well now it works! thanks!